# How to merge two json files with jq

Tags: json, file, merge, jq

I have a directory full of json files with the following structure
e.g.: file1

```
{
    "products": [
        {"f1": "v1"},
        {"f1": "v2"}
    ]
}
```

file2:

```
{
    "products": [
        {"f1": "v3"},
        {"f1": "v4"}
    ]
}
```

The contents of ".products" are not the same as in the example but we can assume that they are well-formed more complicated json values.

I would like to produce a file with the following structure:

```
[
    {"f1": "v1"},
    {"f1": "v2"},
    {"f1": "v3"},
    {"f1": "v4"}
]
```

Any ideas on how to do this using jq?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the following :

```
jq --slurp 'map(.products[])' /path/to/dir/*.json
```

where `/path/to/dir/*.json` should be either a list of files or a [bash glob](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/globbingref.html) that will expand into the list of the JSON files you want to use. For instance for two files `file1` and `file2` in the current directory you can use `file{1,2}`, or simply `file1 file2` which is what the previous glob will be expanded into.

The `--slurp` flag tells `jq` to read all its inputs in an array rather than working on them separately. We then map  each object of this array (the original contents of the files) into the sequence of their products.